# Can I restore the extended partition if I have deleted it?

Tags: windows-7

Please help. I have deleted the extended partition (60 GB) on my 1 TB hard drive. Is there a way I can get it back? Thanks in advance,
                                                  Mihai

Answer (score 0):

In principle you can just recreate the partition table in fdisk, gparted or similar. But you need to know the correct partition start and end positions.